# Addressing performance issues with DDD associations

Tags: performance, domain-driven-design

I know this question has been addressed several times, but I can't seem to find the answer that best fits my scenario.

I am currently struggling at designing associations between entities in a DDD approach, having performance in mind. Let's imagine we have en `Article` entity, with an `Author` entity as attribute. This same `Author` has a `Mail` object as attribute, which is in my design a value object (it could be a regular attribute, but this is just for the sake of the example). Both `Article` and `Author` entities are AR.

Say I want to display a list of articles for a given author. For each article, I only want to display the author's name in some kind of header. At this point, let's say I have a "findByAuthor" method implemented in a `ArticleRepository`.

This method, when called, will return a list of `Article` objects, with their respective `Author` object. This would be enough as I only need the author's name which a simple attribute of the `Author` entity. I don't need the `Mail` object.

In a simple application, with a little consideration for performance, this would be totally OK, but let's imagine for a second that my domain is located on a remote application accessible through a REST API. Transporting a AR list with all their respective associations seems like a huge performance killer when I only need a small part of these associations.

How could I address this issue without considering workarounds like lazy-loading ?

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) use CQRS for such problems. I would just create another aggregate root entity called AuthorArticles and repository for it (every AR needs separate repository).

```
authorArticles = authorArticlesRepository.getByAuthorId(authorId)
```

and that authorArticles in json would look like that:

```
{
    "authorName": "Foo",
    "articles": [
         {
              "title": "Bar",
              "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor"
         },
         {
              "title": "Xyz",
              "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor"
         }
    ]
}
```

It's important that you put into articles objects only data that you need. If you don't need article global id for this query model, then don't put it there.

Comment: Aren't you kind of mixing up CQRS with the "small aggregate" approach here ? A CQRS read model isn't an Aggregate Root nor an Entity.

Comment: CQRS is just a pattern, it can be represented with anything in my opinion and since we are using DDD, then my query model would use separate small aggregate just for read.

Comment: Yet it might be misleading to novices to describe a *read* model in Aggregate terms, as all characteristics traditionally associated with an Aggregate (invariant enforcement, transational boundary, etc.) typically only make sense with regard to the *write* side of things.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I used AR here mainly because of repository. I often read about read models that were not using repositories and were just a raw queries with ORM which is really bad IMO. Of course we can use repository without ARs, but I wanted to be consistent.

Comment: I agree with @guillaume31, the read model should not be using the AR term.  It will cause confusion and it isn't *really consistent* with the CQRS approach :) I usually have an `IQuery` interface that returns the most basic data type that gets the job done.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, yet I feel that consistency inside the domain boundaries should not be addressed by some sort of external responsibility, which would be the case when using the CQRS pattern if I understand it correctly. The client code shouldn't have the responsibility of building a custom query because that would imply in my opinion that the domain doesn't provide what it should be providing in the first place. I then thought about contexts and it occurred to me that insuring consistency doesn't mean much without a context. Could I adress my problem from a context approach ?